# How to find link to a non-public framework in a Xamarin.Mac app

Tags: xamarin, app-store, app-store-connect, xamarin.mac

We're publishing a MacOS app to the app store, which uses Xamarin.Mac and Xamarin Forms. During the review process in App Store Connect, our app binary has been rejected for the following reason:

**Your app app links against the following non-public framework(s):
Frameworks: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Network.framework/Versions/A/Network**

How can we find where this framework is used in our app, so that we can remove it?

Our app is published by posting the .apk file to the app store, but I think we may have to search inside either the .apk, or one of the .dll files - is there any advice for how we can find where in our app this reference is coming from?

We've been recommended to use "strings" or "otool" to help - is there an example of how to use these in our case to find and remove the usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the answer here, as we managed to work out how to detect the referenced frameworks. with thanks to this Xamarin thread too:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/94838/xamarin-mac-linker-behavior-appstore-rejection

As part of the build, we produce a ***.pkg*** file, but also a **.app** file (e.g. **OurApplication.app** and **OurApplication-1.0.pkg**).

It's possible to open the ***.app** file to view the file structure inside, by selecting the file in the Finder, and under options choosing "**Show Package Contents**". This means that opening in a terminal, we can navigate to the location:

`OurApplication.app/Contents/MacOS`

which contains a single Unix executable file: `OurApplication`.

This is the file we need to run `otool` on, with the following command:

`otool -L OurApplication | grep "PrivateFrameworks"`

where we can finally see the framework above that we were referencing. (Note that ignoring the `grep` part of the command would show all the frameworks, so it was useful to apply the filter).

This allowed us to test different build settings to remove the framework, without needing to submit to Apple each time.

We removed the reference (and so fixed the problem) by setting our "Linker behaviour" to "**Framework SDKs Only**" and turning on "**Ahead-of-time (AOT) compile assemblies**" in our project settings.

Comment: Which setting do you have for AOT? There is a combobox and a checkbox.

Comment: We currently have `All` set in the AOT combobox and the `Enable hybrid AOT compiler` checkbox checked